# Can Snowflake DB UDF's execute SQL commands?

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a requirement in Snowflake where I must generate a bit of SQL and then execute it to create a new table.

I have successfully generated the create table statement by creating a UDF (hard-coded at the moment)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COOL_CARGO.test()
  RETURNS STRING 
  AS 
  $$
  SELECT substr(regexp_replace(GET_DDL('TABLE', 'COOL_CARGO.DIM_BRANCH'),('DIM_BRANCH'),'COOL_CARGO.DIM_BRANCH_ERR'), 0, LENGTH(regexp_replace(GET_DDL('TABLE', 'COOL_CARGO.DIM_BRANCH'),('DIM_BRANCH'),'COOL_CARGO.DIM_BRANCH_ERR')) -2)||','||'  etl_err_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  etl_id_run int DEFAULT NULL,
  etl_err_noe int DEFAULT NULL,
  etl_err_desc varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  etl_err_col varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  etl_err_cod varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL'||');'
 $$
 ;
```

This outputs the following

```
create or replace TABLE COOL_CARGO.DIM_BRANCH_ERR (
    TK_BRANCH NUMBER(38,0),
    GB_BRANCH_CODE VARCHAR(256),
    GB_BRANCH_NAME VARCHAR(256),
    GB_BRANCH_CITY VARCHAR(256),
    GB_BRANCH_STATE VARCHAR(256),
    BG_BRANCH_HOME_PORT VARCHAR(256),
    BG_BRANCH_COUNTRY_CODE VARCHAR(256),
    BG_BRANCH_COUNTRY_NAME VARCHAR(256)
,  etl_err_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  etl_id_run int DEFAULT NULL,
  etl_err_noe int DEFAULT NULL,
  etl_err_desc varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  etl_err_col varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  etl_err_cod varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL);
```

I now need to create a UDF that will execute this create table statement but as it only seems to return things like strings, I cannot get it to execute by calling it from another function for example.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COOL_CARGO.run_test()
     RETURNS string
     AS
     $$
     COOL_CARGO.test()
      $$
     ;
```

Then I try and run the function to create the table with

```
select COOL_CARGO.run_test();
```

I do not know if what I want can be done and I would be pretty annoyed if its not possible...

Can this be done in Snowflake DB?

Comment: Snowflake UDFs don't support calling other functions like that, nor eval-like functionality. You'd need stored procedures. They are coming!

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that this was the case :( I dont suppose you have any idea when stored procedures are coming?

Comment: Snowflake community forums is the best place to ask. You might even get access to it early :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Snowflake's new [Stored Procedures feature](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#basic-examples) that launched in **2019**. It allows you to build an arbitrary SQL string and perform an execution in either SQL or JavaScript.

Your existing method can easily be adapted into a stored procedure (example below is illustrative and hasn't been specifically tested):

```
create or replace procedure test()
  returns null
  language javascript
  as
  $$
  var orig_ddl_qry = "SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', 'COOL_CARGO.DIM_BRANCH')";
  var get_ddl_stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
         {
         sqlText: orig_ddl_qry
         }
      );
  var get_ddl_res = get_ddl_stmt.execute();
  get_ddl_res.next();
  var orig_ddl_str = res.getColumnValue(1);
  var replaced_ddl_open = orig_ddl_str.replace("DIM_BRANCH", "COOL_CARGO.DIM_BRANCH_ERR").slice(0, -1);
  var new_ddl = replaced_ddl_open + ", etl_err_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, etl_id_run int DEFAULT NULL, etl_err_noe int DEFAULT NULL, etl_err_desc varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL, etl_err_col varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL, etl_err_cod varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL);";
  var create_stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
         {
         sqlText: new_ddl
         }
      );
  var create_ddl_res = create_stmt.execute();
  $$
  ;

CALL test();
```